# Ajax is not calling php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

what is wrong with my code? He doesn't do the alert 'PHPPPPP'
Only the success one

Html:
Add to Log

```
          <script>
            function create () {
              $.ajax({
                  url:"log.php",    //the page containing php script
                  type: "post",    //request type,
                  data: {hour: "1", min: "2", email: "3"},
                  success:function(result){
                     alert("passed");
                  }, error: function(data) {
                      alert(data);
                  }
              });
          }
        </script>
```

Php(log.php):

```
echo "<script> alert('PHPPPPPPPPPP') </script> " ;
```

Comment: Well, it's not doing anything with the data it gets back (`result`).

Comment: @MinusFour but it isn't supossed to alert anyway?

Comment: While it's not strictly a duplicate, having a read of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) may be beneficial to you in helping to understand what is/isn't happening.

Comment: @Muax - you'll only see an alert when that Javascript code is executed by a browser, but that won't happen on its own when you request via Ajax. You get some data back, that happens to be HTML containing a JS script, but the browser won't know to execute that JS.

Comment: `but it isn't supossed to alert anyway?`...which alert? It should run `alert("passed");` if the request didn't fail. It won't run the script you echoed from PHP - that's stored in `result` but you're ignoring it. And it makes no sense to return actual JS from PHP in the response to an AJAX request. Just return some data, and write JS in your actual JS area to run whatever you need. Separation of concerns, and all that...

Comment: Ohhhh but if i do something like insert on a sql table, is the php file able to do using ajax? I think im not doing the ajax thing right @RobinZigmond

Comment: the PHP script, which runs on the server, can do anything it wants. But if you want to do anything with what it `echo`s back in response, it's the responsibility of the Javascript code that makes the Ajax request to deal with that. It's not the same as the user loading a page "normally" in the browser and having the HTML response (including any embedded CSS/JS/etc) handled automatically by the browser.

Comment: well i have this code on log.php and it doesn't work but if i delete the log.php the alert fail open up :
<?php
session_start();
include('conexao.php');

if(!$_SESSION['usuario']) {
 header('Location: indexM.php');
 exit();
}

$usuario=$_SESSION['usuario'];
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO login.times (`usuario`,`date`,`time`) VALUES ('{$usuario}','1','2');");

Comment: `but if i do something like insert on a sql table, is the php file able to do using ajax?`...yes absolutely. That has nothing to do with JS or AJAX, or how you process the response etc. It's just standard PHP. PHP can execute that, no matter which way you send the request to it.

Comment: `header('Location: indexM.php'); exit();` won't work as you expect in an AJAX context. AJAX calls don't follow Location redirect headers. You need a different mechanism for rejecting unauthenticated requests when it's an AJAX call - e.g. simply returning a 403 status. P.S. `doesn't work` isn't a useful description of your problem. Give details of error messages or the precise unexpected behaviour. If you don't have that information to give us, then do some debugging in order to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the script to your document. Since you are using `jQuery`:

```
      <script>
        function create () {
          $.ajax({
              url:"log.php",    //the page containing php script
              type: "post",    //request type,
              data: {hour: "1", min: "2", email: "3"},
              success:function(result){
                 alert("passed");
                 $('body').append(result);
              }, error: function(data) {
                  alert(data);
              }
          });
      }
    </script>
```

This will simply add the `script` to the `body` element. It would be better if you just omit the HTML and instead just `echo` the string so you could `alert` the result instead of adding a script to your document.